# Error running systemctl to start service in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: systemd, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to build a simple Apache/PHP server using the Amazon Linux 2 image. I have the following:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y &&\
    amazon-linux-extras install php7.4 -y &&\
    yum update -y &&\
    yum install httpd -y

COPY --chown=root:root docker/script/startup /startup

ENTRYPOINT /startup
```

**startup**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p /run/dbus              # Added this based on other SO question
dbus-daemon --system            # Added this based on other SO question

systemctl enable dbus           # Added this based on other SO question
systemctl start dbus            # Added this based on other SO question
systemctl status dbus           # Added this based on other SO question

systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl status httpd

/bin/bash
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  build: .
  container_name: "${APP_NAME}-app"
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: "${WEB_HOST}"
  env_file:
    - ./.env-local
  working_dir: "/${APP_NAME}/app"
  restart: "no"
  privileged: true              # Added this based on other SO question
  volumes:
    - "./app:/${APP_NAME}/app:ro"
    - ./docker:/docker
    - "./conf:/${APP_NAME}/conf:ro"
    - "./vendor:/${APP_NAME}/vendor:ro"
    - "./conf:/var/www/conf:ro"
    - "./web:/var/www/html/"
  depends_on:
    - composer
```

I run this with the following command:

```
docker run -it web bash
```

And this is what it gives me:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service, pointing to /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this or how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to avoid systemd service units in a docker image.

Instead use `cronttab` script with `@boot` directive/selector.

In addition dbus is centrally managed by kernel and not allowed at container level.
If `Docker` service is up then you probably have dbus active and running.

You can add capabilities to the root user running in the container. Read more [here](https://training.play-with-docker.com/security-capabilities/).

As last resort try to disable SELinux in your docker image.

Comment: Hi @Dudi Boy, I am trying to resolve the above issue as per the suggestions posted here. However facing some difficulties. I have created another ticket. Could you please help. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641314/unable-to-run-systemctl-start-command-on-amazon-linux-2-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue trying to run systemctl from within the Amazon Linux 2 docker image

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

# update and install httpd 2.4.53, php 7.4.28 with php extensions
RUN yum update -y; yum clean all
RUN yum install -y httpd amazon-linux-extras
RUN amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4
RUN yum clean metadata
RUN yum install -y php php-{pear,cli,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip}

# update website files
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY phpinfo.php /var/www/html
RUN chown -R apache:apache /var/www
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-DFOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

$ docker build -t azl1
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name azl1_web azl1

pointing a browser to the IP:8080/phpinfo.php brought up the normal phpinfo page as expected pointing to a successful php 7.4.28 installation.